# Query with dynamic date intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Given a statuses table that holds information about products availability, how do I select the date that corresponds to the 1st day in the latest 20 days that the product has been active?

Yes I know the question is hard to follow. I think another way to put it would be: I want to know how many times each product has been sold in the last 20 days that it was active, meaning the product could have been active for years, but I'd only want the sales count from the latest 20 days that it had a status of "active".

It's something easily doable in the server-side (i.e. getting any collection of products from the DB, iterating them, performing n+1 queries on the statuses table, etc), but I have hundreds of thousands of items so it's imperative to do it in SQL for performance reasons.

table : products

```
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |   name    |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |   Apple   |
|   2   |   Banana  |
|   3   |   Grape   |
+-------+-----------+
```

table : statuses

```
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|   id  |     name    |   product_id  |   created_at  |
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|   1   |   active    |            1  |   2018-01-01  |
|   2   |   inactive  |            1  |   2018-02-01  |
|   3   |   active    |            1  |   2018-03-01  |
|   4   |   inactive  |            1  |   2018-03-15  |
|   6   |   active    |            1  |   2018-04-25  |
|   7   |   active    |            2  |   2018-03-01  |
|   8   |   active    |            3  |   2018-03-10  |
|   9   |   inactive  |            3  |   2018-03-15  |
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

table : items (ordered products)

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|   id  |   product_id  |   order_id  |
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|   1   |            1  |          1  |
|   2   |            1  |          2  |
|   3   |            1  |          3  |
|   4   |            1  |          4  |
|   5   |            1  |          5  |
|   6   |            2  |          3  |
|   7   |            2  |          4  |
|   8   |            2  |          5  |
|   9   |            3  |          5  |
+-------+---------------+-------------+
```

table : orders

```
+-------+---------------+
|   id  |   created_at  |
+-------+---------------+
|   1   |   2018-01-02  |
|   2   |   2018-01-15  |
|   3   |   2018-03-02  |
|   4   |   2018-03-10  |
|   5   |   2018-03-13  |
+-------+---------------+
```

I want my final results to look like this:

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   id  |   name    |  recent_sales_count  |  date_to_start_counting_sales  |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   1   |   Apple   |                   3  |                    2018-01-30  |
|   2   |   Banana  |                   0  |                    2018-04-09  |
|   3   |   Grape   |                   1  |                    2018-03-10  |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

So this is what I mean by latest 20 active days for e.g. Apple:

- It was last activated at '2018-04-25'. That's **4 days** ago.
- Before that, it was inactive since '2018-03-15', so all these days until '2018-04-25' don't count.
- Before that, it was active since '2018-03-01'. That's more **14 days** until '2018-03-15'.
- Before that, inactive since '2018-02-01'.
- Finally, it was active since '2018-01-01', so it should only count the missing **2 days** (4 + 14 + 2 = 20) backwards from '2018-02-01', resulting in date_to_start_counting_sales = '2018-01-30'.
- With the '2018-01-30' date in hand, I'm then able to count Apple orders in the last 20 active days: 3.

Hope that makes sense.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7817f) with the data provided above.

Comment: Can you double check the `date_to_start_counting_sales` in your desired results (assuming your using YYYY-MM-DD)? And please provide an example of what you mean by "the last 20 days that it was active" for one of the products. E.g. Apple was last active '2018-04-25', so all sales from '2018-04-25' to '2018-05-15'? Or do you want the last active time where a full 20 day interval exists? I'm unable work backwards from your data on how you got to those desired results with the info provided.

Comment: @krokodilko As I mentioned, I've tried solving the problem in the server-side language, and I have a problem getting it done in SQL. Thanks for your awesome collaboration.

Comment: @Mallorie Thanks! I fixed the dates and added an explanation on how I'd get the desired result for Apple. Please let me know if that still doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have read your "finally" point 5 times : I understand how you get your 20 days of active apples, but I dont understand how you get the date 2018-01-30 from that. Beside this, since MySQL doesn't have window functions, that will be hard to achieve in straight SQL (without a procedure)

Comment: Thanks rzb, that makes sense now. Thinking the same thing as @Thomas G though... could figure something out in PL/SQL (albeit ugly), but mysql seems limited. And mysql is not my forte. I'll ponder it and get back if anything comes to mind.

Comment: @ThomasG I'm just counting 20 active days backwards, ignoring inactive intervals. The total active days would be 49 (since it was first made active at '2018-01-01'), but since I only need 20 days, I only need 2 more at that point. So ''2018-02-01' -2 days. Pretty hard to explain and I guess even harder to understand =(

Comment: @Mallorie If you could post what you got with PL/SQL that would probably be a great starting point for me. Thanks!

Comment: man your are giving me a headache on a Sunday morning... ok trying to understand that again. Could you prepare a fiddle with your structure and data so we can have a playground ?

Comment: @ThomasG Updated the question with link to **final** fiddle.

Comment: this will already be a great help : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7817f/3  I've still hard to understand the rest, but from my query here, it will be peanuts for sure. I grab a coffee and I finish this

Comment: plsql would still take a lot of time to write, and pretty much impossible to translate to mysql... so i messed with mysql instead. Been wanting to learn it anyway. Hope it helps. Got me obsessed with this problem now! ha

Comment: Can products be ordered when they are not active?  Does a product typically get ordered once per day?  If so, just use the last 20 days of orders.  And, why is the question tagged MySQL if you are writing PL/SQL code.  Oracle and MySQL have very different capabilities.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, they can't be ordered when not active. And they can be ordered 0-N times per day. Some products typically only sell on certain dates. I got what you suggest but unfortunately there's no specific pattern. And no, I'm not writing any PL/SQL code, it's MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a standard SQL solution, that does not use any window function as you are on MySQL 5

My solution requires 3 stacked views.

It would have been better with a CTE but your version doesn't support it. Same goes for the stacked Views... I don't like to stack views and always try to avoid it, but sometimes you have no other choice, because MySQL doesn't accept subqueries in FROM clause for Views.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_product_dates AS
(
        SELECT product_id, created_at AS active_date,
                (
                    SELECT created_at
                    FROM statuses ti
                    WHERE name = 'inactive' AND ta.created_at < ti.created_at AND ti.product_id=ta.product_id
                    GROUP BY product_id
                ) AS inactive_date
        FROM statuses ta
        WHERE name = 'active'
);

CREATE VIEW VIEW_product_dates_days AS
(
    SELECT product_id, active_date, inactive_date, datediff(IFNULL(inactive_date, SYSDATE()),active_date) AS nb_days
    FROM VIEW_product_dates
);

CREATE VIEW VIEW_product_dates_days_cumul AS
(
    SELECT product_id, active_date, ifnull(inactive_date,sysdate()) AS inactive_date,  nb_days,
         IFNULL((SELECT SUM(V2.nb_days) + V1.nb_days
                 FROM VIEW_product_dates_days V2
                 WHERE V2.active_date >= IFNULL(V1.inactive_date, SYSDATE()) AND V1.product_id=V2.product_id
                ),V1.nb_days) AS cumul_days
    FROM  VIEW_product_dates_days V1
);
```

The final view produce this :

```
| product_id |          active_date |        inactive_date | nb_days | cumul_days |
|------------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|------------|
|          1 | 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-02-01T00:00:00Z |      31 |         49 |
|          1 | 2018-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z |      14 |         18 |
|          1 | 2018-04-25T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-29T11:28:39Z |       4 |          4 |
|          2 | 2018-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-29T11:28:39Z |      59 |         59 |
|          3 | 2018-03-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z |       5 |          5 |
```

So it aggregates all active periods of all products, it counts the number of days for each period, and the cumulative days of all past active periods since current date.

Then we can query this final view to get the desired date for each product. I set a variable for your 20 days, so you can change that number easily if you want.

```
SET @cap_days = 20 ;

SELECT PD.id, Pd.name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.created_at > PD.date_to_start_counting_sales THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recent_sales_count  ,
       PD.date_to_start_counting_sales
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*,
           (CASE WHEN LowerCap.max_cumul_days IS NULL 
                 THEN ADDDATE(ifnull(HigherCap.min_inactive_date,sysdate()),(-@cap_days))
                 ELSE 
                 CASE WHEN LowerCap.max_cumul_days < @cap_days AND  HigherCap.min_inactive_date IS NULL
                      THEN ADDDATE(ifnull(LowerCap.max_inactive_date,sysdate()),(-LowerCap.max_cumul_days))
                      ELSE ADDDATE(ifnull(HigherCap.min_inactive_date,sysdate()),(LowerCap.max_cumul_days-@cap_days))
                 END
            END) as date_to_start_counting_sales
    FROM products P
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT product_id, MAX(cumul_days) AS max_cumul_days, MAX(inactive_date) AS max_inactive_date
        FROM VIEW_product_dates_days_cumul
        WHERE cumul_days <= @cap_days
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) LowerCap ON P.id=LowerCap.product_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT product_id, MIN(cumul_days) AS min_cumul_days, MIN(inactive_date) AS min_inactive_date
        FROM VIEW_product_dates_days_cumul
        WHERE cumul_days > @cap_days
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) HigherCap ON P.id=HigherCap.product_id
) PD
LEFT JOIN items i ON PD.id =  i.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = i.order_id 
GROUP BY PD.id, Pd.name, PD.date_to_start_counting_sales
```

Returns

```
| id |   name | recent_sales_count | date_to_start_counting_sales |
|----|--------|--------------------|------------------------------|
|  1 |  Apple |                  3 |         2018-01-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | Banana |                  0 |         2018-04-09T20:43:23Z |
|  3 |  Grape |                  1 |         2018-03-10T00:00:00Z |
```

FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/804f52/24

Comment: Awesome! You made it look simple, ty very much. One thing though would it be possible to show results for currently inactive products too instead of null? I'll try to get my head around this and tweak your queries.

Comment: yes but what would be the logic for inactive products ?

Comment: Same logic: 20 last active days. e.g. if the same Apple product was made inactive today, it should still give the same results forever until it's made active again.

Comment: Also, the really important column is the recent_sales_count (see my "desired results" table). The date_to_start_counting_sales (your target_date) would be there just so I can use it as starting date to count orders.

Comment: Changing the variable to something like 15 gives wrong results. Probably because it's only counting days and ignoring months.

Comment: First try my updated solution (fiddle link updated too), we'll see after that. recent_sales_count will be easy to compute

Comment: Nice! That's correct for the inactive products. But if you change cap_days to 10, Apple should have a date_to_start_counting_sales of '2018-03-09', not '2018-01-26'.

Comment: I give up. Its late in Europe and  I am too tired to brainstorm this correctly. I know that the final touch is close but I can't see it because I have to sleep.  I still have updated the fiddle and answer with the recent_sales_count. If someone else want to fork my answer to  finish it, please do... a job for @GordonLinoff :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of MySql you're working with, but if you can use 8.0, that version came out with a lot of functionality that makes things slightly more doable (CTE's, row_number(), partition, etc.).

My recommendation would be to create a view like in this [DB-Fiddle Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j46wgx5sxZbDFgrB6HVZX8/0), call the view on server side and iterate programatically. There are ways of doing it in SQL, but it'd be a bear to write, test and likely would be less efficient.

Assumptions:

1. Products cannot be sold during inactive date ranges
2. `Statuses` table will always alternate status active/inactive/active for each product. I.e. no date ranges where a certain product is both active and inactive.

View Results:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| product_id | active_date | end_date   | days_active |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 2018-01-01  | 2018-02-01 | 31          |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 2018-03-01  | 2018-03-15 | 14          |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 2018-04-25  | 2018-04-29 | 4           |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 2          | 2018-03-01  | 2018-04-29 | 59          |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 3          | 2018-03-10  | 2018-03-15 | 5           |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW days_active AS (
WITH active_rn 
     AS (SELECT *, Row_number() 
                    OVER ( partition BY NAME, product_id 
                    ORDER BY created_at) AS rownum 
         FROM   statuses
         WHERE name = 'active'),
     inactive_rn 
     AS (SELECT *, Row_number() 
                    OVER ( partition BY NAME, product_id 
                    ORDER BY created_at) AS rownum 
         FROM   statuses
         WHERE name = 'inactive') 
SELECT x1.product_id, 
       x1.created_at AS active_date, 
       CASE WHEN x2.created_at IS NULL 
            THEN Curdate()
            ELSE x2.created_at 
       END AS end_date, 
       CASE WHEN x2.created_at IS NULL 
             THEN Datediff(Curdate(), x1.created_at) 
            ELSE  Datediff(x2.created_at,x1.created_at) 
        END AS days_active 
FROM   active_rn x1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN inactive_rn x2 
                    ON x1.rownum = x2.rownum 
                       AND x1.product_id = x2.product_id ORDER  BY 
x1.product_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on MySQL 5.7, but I like the view idea. The problem though is the N+1 number of queries needed to count items for each product if I do it on server side. I have hundreds of products and hundreds of thousands of orders/items to calculate recent sales for. It just takes minutes/times out. I could try changing the timeout limit, running the script on a background process, caching the results, etc; but it'd be my last resort due to the required architecture.

Comment: To clarify, i mean use the view results to get the `date_to_start_counting_sales` programatially. That's the part you probably shouldn't attempt in SQL. Once you have that, just pass the date into a  `select` statement. Or look at your iteration again because pretty much any ORM has a way around the n+1 issue. Lots of stack overflow answers on that. Much luck to you!